# Minikube Ingress route and ping not working on windows

Tags: windows, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, minikube

I installed a minikube with docker desktop driver on windows. I enabled the ingress addons after starting the minikube.

[image: ingress addons]

Following is the ingress I created.
[image: Ingress]

When I am pinging the Ingress IP, I am getting a timeout,
[image]

I opened the tunnel as well after starting the minikube as suggested,
[image]

Still the ping is not working. Also I am not able to reach the REST service that i deployed. I added the hostname and the IP in the etc/hosts file.

here is my deployment.yml -

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: demo-shipit
  labels:
    app: demo-shipit
    platform: dms
    component: service
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: demo-shipit
      platform: dms
      component: service
  replicas: 2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: demo-shipit
        platform: dms
        component: service
    spec:
      restartPolicy: Always
      containers:
        - name: demo-shipit
          image: demo:latest
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
          resources:
            limits:
              memory: "512Mi"
          envFrom:
            - configMapRef:
                name: demo-shipit
```

here is my service.yml -

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: demo-shipit
  labels:
    app: demo-shipit
    platform: dms
    component: service
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 8080
      protocol: TCP
      name: http
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: demo-shipit
    platform: dms
    component: service
```

Here is my ingress.yml -

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: demo-shipit
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
spec:
  rules:
    - host: demoshipt.test
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: demo-shipit
                port:
                  number: 80
```

Here is my hosts/etc

```
192.168.49.2 demoshipt.test
172.17.0.15 hello-world.info
# Added by Docker Desktop
10.70.0.50 host.docker.internal
10.70.0.50 gateway.docker.internal
# To allow the same kube context to work on the host and the container:
127.0.0.1 kubernetes.docker.internal
# End of section
```

I have a deployment.yml, one service.yaml and one ingress.yml which i can share on request.
Can you please let me know if I am missing anything.

Comment: does `curl demoshipt.test` work?

Comment: No, it does not.

Comment: can you edit your question and add show how the `/etc/hosts` looks like? also share the deployment and service YAML for your REST API

Comment: Hi @Sibtain, I have edited the question and added the ymls as requested.

Comment: Are you able to access your service using `curl <svc-ip>:80`. If not, you might want to check your pod `kubectl exec -i -t <pod-name> -- curl localhost:8080`

Answer (score 0):

Please run the below commands to reach the `REST` service that was deployed.

```
minikube tunnel
```

This command exposes the **external IP** directly to any program running on the host operating system.

```
minikube service <<YOUR_SERVICE_NAME>>
```

This command will create a tunnel to access your application which is exposed using the service from outside of the Kubernetes cluster and also it returns the Kubernetes URL(s) for service(s) in your local cluster.

Please see the [documentation](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/commands/service/) for more [details](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/ingress-minikube/).

Comment: i ran both the commands. Its showing me 2 IPs,
http://127.0.0.1:59920/ - working
 http://192.168.49.2:30555 - not working
What i am expecting to have is  http://192.168.49.2:80 to access my service which is working as well.

Comment: I meant not working. Sorry for the typo.

Comment: Can you please provide your input for the question asked by Sibtain

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late reply. I found out from different posts that it may not be possible to make the minikube tunnel work in windows. So i installed virtualBox(ubuntu) and configured minikube inside it. It started working without the tunnel. Thanks for all the help!